# Temperature modelling

Tags: temperature, thermal-radiation

I have to find a mathematical model for the temperature vs. time to study the temperature of the environment next to a lamp. This lamp is made off and on on, let's say, a daily basis

The lamp is starting together with a cooldown which stabilizes during the first time of use. After the lamp off, another cooling starts.

When a lamp is working, I see kind of two gauss curves mberged together (two peask), with right skewing.

So, I'm considering two functions $F$ which are adding together.

But, what should $F$ be? I don't know black body temperatures equations, but if they exists, they should fit well. I was also thinking about Weibull distribution but that only because I know it looks like this, and it suffers of the fact that it is not continuous.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's been simultaneously posted to multiple SE sites. If we determine that it's on topic here, we can reopen it.

Comment: Indeed, that was not very fair to push it on two forums, but I did that because it involves lots of physics ... for big data purposes. I don't think that big data specialists are best suited to define that $F$ which is IMHO a modelisation of black body's behavior. On the other hand, at the end, that predictive analysis ... so data science.
So, could you please leave it open? Thanks

Comment: When the same question is posted on multiple sites, that usually means it's not clear whether it's on topic for either of them, which I think is the case here. If you were to adapt your question to each site - i.e. ask the physics part of the question here, and the data science part of it on [datascience.SE] - then it would probably be fine.

Comment: Indeed, I'm sorry about that.
I definitely think that it's more a physics problem, so I've removed the question about the quality of the model and I've cancelled the post on DataScience. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, it's one of those things that you learn with experience. I suppose I'll reopen this question, then, but I still think it could be edited to make the physics aspects more prominent. We'll see what the community thinks.

Comment: Thanks David. I've completely edited it to make the physical aspects (black body?) more visible. Best regards.

Comment: Ah, in my opinion that is _much_ better suited to this site. Thanks!

Comment: Can you specify more your question? Specifically what is the environment of the lamp which you want to monitor? Do you just have a thermal detector of some kind? or do you sample something else? what kind of lamp? for example, in a light bulb the filament arrives to hundreds of degrees almost instantaneously, but the crystal bulb will take longer to achieve an equilibrium temperature, and air around might not be much affected, but if there are surfaces close which might heat up, the there will be air currents which modify the heating of surface, and whole equilibrium might be more complex.

Comment: Hello rmhleo. The environment is a digital cinema projector. It uses a Xenon lamp. I have multiple sensors on different locations of the projector.